# Why people invent discrete mathematics like propositional logic, logical equivalences, predicate logic, etc?

Tags: math-history

I'm now learning discrete mathematics. I wonder why they invent discrete mathematics. For example, a english sentence "some lion drink coffee" can be translated into statement using predicate logic: ∃x ∈D, L(x) ^ C(x) (D is the set of all creatures; L(x) is x is a lion; C(x) is x drinks coffee)
I wonder Why they do that. I'm studying computer science. Discrete mathematics is one of the core course. What's the relation of translating natural language to symbolic things and computer itself?

Comment: Discrete math is at the heart of computer science, as (modern digital) computers are discrete things that do math. That doesn't necessarily mean that every single part of discrete math is directly relevant to understanding how computers work. In this particular case, I personally can't immediately think of anything, but then again, I'm no computer scientist. Have you tried asking your professors why they have chosen to include this particular topic?

Comment: You will indeed rarely meet lions drinking coffee in your future professional life... But for example, have you heard of Prolog, a programming language that is (almost) entirely based on this kind of logic (first order logic) ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Gottlob Frege's brother was confused about feline coffee drinking habits, and Frege invented first-order logic to help clear things up.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Comment: To analyze and elucidate complex mathematical and philosophical issues due to ambiguities in natural language use.

Comment: See this [book](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/602371df-dc57-4f52-8b30-80edf1f04d88/1004853.pdf)